# angularjs scope.$watch and expression with square brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found some legacy code in the product that I work on:

```
$scope.$watch("[timeRange]", function() {
  doStuff();
}, true);
```

timeRange is an object on the scope.

I don't understand this syntax of watching something with square brackets round it.  I have searched the web and the angularjs documentation and still can't work it out.  Can someone help explain what this construct means?

Comment: it seems to me like a mix up between angularjs and angular. The square brackets shouldn't be there in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a mix up between **$watch and $watchGroup**. Accordding the doc:

> $watchGroup(watchExpressions, listener); 
>   A variant of $watch() where
>   it watches an array of watchExpressions. If any one expression in the
>   collection changes the listener is executed.
>
> The items in the watchExpressions array are observed via the standard
>   $watch operation. Their return values are examined for changes on
>   every call to $digest. The listener is called whenever any expression
>   in the watchExpressions array changes.

Answer (score 0):

$watch can be applied on variables and objects with same syntax

```
$scope.$watch("timeRange", function() {
      doStuff();
    }, true);
```

Comment: There is no explanation here